# How to get the selected value of a dropdown in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

How do I get the selected value in the dropdown

HTML Code:

```html
<select  name="appealStatusId" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="1">
      Pending
  </option>

  <option value="2">
      Overall Appeal Approved
  </option>

  <option value="3" selected="selected">
      Overall Appeal Not Approved
  </option>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected value in the dropdown you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  SelectElement status = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[name='appealStatusId']")));
  IWebElement selected = status.SelectedOption;
  Console.Write(selected.Text);
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  SelectElement status = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='appealStatusId']")));
  IWebElement selected = status.SelectedOption;
  Console.Write(selected.Text);
  ```
- Using *Name*:

  ```
  SelectElement status = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("appealStatusId")));
  IWebElement selected = status.SelectedOption;
  Console.Write(selected.Text);
  ```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element based on it's Value, Text or Id in dropdown options.

By using text:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("your_URL");

driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

IWebElement element_name = driver.FindElement(By.Name("appealStatusId"));

SelectElement statusId = new SelectElement(element_name);

// To print all available options    
Console.WriteLine(statusId.Options);

// To iterate over the dropdown options and select the one which matches with the text you want to select
foreach(IWebElement  element in statusId.Options)
     {
          if(element.Text == "Overall Appeal Not Approved")
          {
               element.Click();
          }
     }
```

Or by using SelectByValue:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("your_URL");

driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

IWebElement element_name = driver.FindElement(By.Name("appealStatusId"));

SelectElement statusId = new SelectElement(element_name);

statusId.SelectByValue("3");
```